# Searching for target in Excel spreadsheet using R

Tags: r, excel

As an R noob, I'm currently rather stumped by what is probably a rather trivial problem. I have data that looks like in the second image below, essentially a long sheet of rows with values in three columns. What I need is for a way to scan the sheet looking for particular combinations of values in the first and second column - combinations that are specified in a second spreadsheet of targets (see picture 1). When that particular combination is found, I need the script to extract the whole row in question from the data file.

So far, I've managed to read the files without problem:

```
library(xlsx)

folder <- 'C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\R EXCEL test\\'

target_file <- paste(folder,(readline(prompt = "Enter filename for target list:")),sep = "")

data_file <- paste(folder,(readline(prompt = "Enter data file:")),sep = "")

targetsDb <- read.xlsx(target_file, sheetName = "Sheet1")
data <- read.xlsx(data_file, sheetName = "Sheet1")

targets <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)

for(i in 1:nrow(targetsDb)){
  targets[[i]] <- c(targetsDb[i,1],targetsDb[i,2])
}
```

And with the last command I've managed to save the target combinations as items in a list. However, I run into trouble when it comes to iterating through the file looking for any of those combinations of cell values in the first two columns. My approach was to create a list with one item,

```
SID_IA <- vector(mode = "list", length = 1)
```

and to fill it with the values of column 1 and 2 iteratively for each row of the data file:

```
for(n in 1:nrow(data)){
  SID_IA[[n]] <- c(data[n,1],data[n,2])
```

I would then nest another for loop here, which basically goes through every row in the targets sheet to check if the combination of values currently in the SID_IA list matches any of the target ones. Then at the end of the loop, the list is emptied so it can be filled with the following combination of data values.

```
  for(i in targets){
    if(SID_IA[[n]] %in% targets){
      print(SID_IA[[n]], "in sentence" , data[n,1], "is ", data[n,3])
    }else{
      print(FALSE)
    }
    SID_IA[[n]] <- NULL  
  }
}
```

However, if I try to run that last loop, it returns the following output and error:

```
[1] FALSE
Error in SID_IA[[n]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In if (SID_IA[[n]] %in% targets) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So, it seems to be doing something for at least one iteration, but then crashes. I'm sure I'm missing something very elementary, but I just can't see it. Any ideas?

EDIT: As requested, I've removed the images and made the test Excel sheets available [here](http://www.filedropper.com/targets) and [here](http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/data_32).

Comment: It'd be much easier to look into it if you provided a short sample of real data. A link to a short excel sheet would do.

Comment: And looking at it i think it would have been infinitely easier to do with a data.frame  instead of a list

Comment: @R.S. I'll try to upload a spreadsheet somewhere when I'm back on a computer, but if you have any suggestions on how to simplify the process I'm all ears.

Comment: @R.S. Links to the spreadsheets are now available at the end of the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. I'm attempting an answer that should require minimum use of fancy tricks.

```
data<- xlsx::read.xlsx(file = "Data.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1)
target<-  xlsx::read.xlsx(file = "Targets.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1)

head(data)
target
```

These values are already in data.frame format. If all you want to know is which rows  appear exactly same in data and target, then it will be as simple as finding a merge

```
merge(target,data,all = F)
```

If, on the other hand , you want to keep the data table with a marking of target rows, then the easiest way will be to make an index column

```
data$indx<- 1:nrow(data)
data
mrg<- merge(target,data,all = F)
data$test<- rep("test", nrow(data))
data$test[mrg$indx]<- "target"

data
```

This is like the original image you'd posted.

BTW , if yo are on a graphical interface you can also use File dialogue to open data files.. check out file.choose()

Comment: I will give this a shot in the morning, but what I want is to use the combinations of values in adjacent cells in the Target file to find specific rows in the Data file. Then copy those rows to output them to a different spreadsheet, but I haven't gotten around to tackling that last bit yet.

Comment: Thank you @R.S.! it looks like merge really does what I need it to, and I can output the target lines to a new file. Now I'm trying to do the opposite, i.e. extracting the non-target lines to a new data frame. I've tried playing around with the "all" argument, but I seem to get the same output.

Comment: happy it helped. if you use the second approach, you can just decide weather you want too keep rows with "test" or "target" . Like : `data[data$test=="test", c(1:3)]` will select only rows where the test column has value "test" and clumnns 1 to 3.  BTW merge also optionally takes column names , in case the two dataframes have different columns names

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Following from @R.S.'s suggestion that didn't involve vectors and loops, and after some playing around, I have figured out how to extract the target lines, and then how to remove them from the original data, outputting both results. I'm leaving it here for future reference and considering this solved.

```
extracted <- merge(targets,data,all = F)
write.xlsx(extracted,output_file1)

combined <-rbind(data,extracted)
minus.target <- combined[!duplicated(combined,fromLast = FALSE)&!duplicated(combined,fromLast = TRUE),]
write.xls(minus.target,output_file2)
```